# Как преобразовать необработанный текст в json файл

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

У меня есть необработанный текст, который выглядит вот так:

```
1. Общие положения
    1. Настоящее положение о формах, периодичности, порядке текущего контроля успеваемости, промежуточной и итоговой аттестации обучающихся групповой и индивидуальной форм обучения (далее - Положение) структурном подразделении государственного бюджетного общеобразовательного учреждения «Республиканский физико-математический лицей-интернат» «Детский технопарк «Кванториум-15» (далее – ГБОУ РФМЛИ, Кванториум) разработано в соответствии с Федеральным законом РФ от 29.12.2012 №273-Ф3 «Об образовании в Российской Федерации», Приказом Минпросвещения России от 09.11.2018 года № 196 «Об утверждении Порядка организации и осуществления образовательной деятельности по дополнительным общеобразовательным программам», Уставом ГБОУ РФМЛИ и регламентирует содержание, порядок проведения текущего контроля успеваемости, промежуточной и итоговой аттестации обучающихся групповой и индивидуальной форм обучения Кванториума.
    2. Текущий контроль успеваемости, промежуточная и итоговая аттестация обучающихся групповой и индивидуальной форм являются неотъемлемой частью образовательной деятельности, которая сопровождает освоение дополнительной общеобразовательной программы и позволяет участникам образовательного процесса оценить реальную результативность их совместной творческой деятельности.
    3. Цель текущего контроля и аттестаций - выявление уровня обученности, развития способностей о обучающихся, приобретенных компетенций и их соответствие прогнозируемым результатам дополнительной общеобразовательной программы.

2. Текущий контроль успеваемости обучающихся
    1. Текущий контроль успеваемости обучающихся в Кванториума осуществляется педагогом по каждой пройденному кейсу.
    2. Форму текущего контроля определяет педагог с учетом контингента обучающихся, уровня обученности обучающихся, содержания учебного материала, используемых им образовательных технологий и др.
    3. Текущий контроль может проводиться в следующих формах: творческие работы, самостоятельные работы репродуктивного характера; выставки; вопросники, тестирование; защита творческих работ, проектов; конференция; фестиваль; олимпиада; соревнование; турнир.

3. Организация входного контроля обучающихся
    1. Входной контроль в Кванториуме не проводится в связи с тем, что прием обучающихся осуществляется на основании добровольного волеизъявления детей или их родителей (законных представителей) согласно порядку электронной записи и проводится на принципах равных условий приема для всех поступающих, за исключением лиц, которым в соответствии с Федеральным законом предоставлены особые права (преимущества) при приеме на обучение.
```

Передо мной стоит задача написать QA-модель для ответа на вопросы по этому тексту, для этого мне надо привести этот текст к JSON-формату вида:

```
{
   "context": "Question",
   "idx": 1 {
   "answers":[
            {
               "text":"1. Настоящее положение о формах, периодичности, порядке текущего контроля успеваемости, промежуточной и итоговой аттестации обучающихся групповой и индивидуальной форм обучения (далее - Положение) структурном подразделении государственного бюджетного общеобразовательного учреждения «Республиканский физико-математический лицей-интернат» «Детский технопарк «Кванториум-15» (далее – ГБОУ РФМЛИ, Кванториум) разработано в соответствии с Федеральным законом РФ от 29.12.2012 №273-Ф3 «Об образовании в Российской Федерации», Приказом Минпросвещения России от 09.11.2018 года № 196 «Об утверждении Порядка организации и осуществления образовательной деятельности по дополнительным общеобразовательным программам», Уставом ГБОУ РФМЛИ и регламентирует содержание, порядок проведения текущего контроля успеваемости, промежуточной и итоговой аттестации обучающихся групповой и индивидуальной форм обучения Кванториума.
                       2 Текущий контроль успеваемости, промежуточная и итоговая аттестация обучающихся групповой и индивидуальной форм являются неотъемлемой частью образовательной деятельности, которая сопровождает освоение дополнительной общеобразовательной программы и позволяет участникам образовательного процесса оценить реальную результативность их совместной творческой деятельности.
                       3.  Цель текущего контроля и аттестаций - выявление уровня обученности, развития способностей обучающихся, приобретенных компетенций и их соответствие прогнозируемым результатам дополнительной общеобразовательной программы.


            }      
   }
           ]
}
```

Как написать код на python с обработкой необразованного текста и преобразования в json формат?

Comment: необработанный текст всегда имеет нумерацию строк?

Comment: А куда раздел делся, он не нужен?

Comment: Нет, не нужен. Всегда имеет нумерацию @CrazyElf

Answer (score -1):

Со стороны это выглядит как полноценная задача, а не вопрос.
Если абстрагироваться, то я бы писал парсер, который на вход принимает строку,  считает вложенность (как отступы в питоне) и берет первое число до точки после отступа.
т.е. если отсупов нет - вложение первого уровня, 4 отступа - 2-ого и так далее.
Но такой парсер быстро ляжет, если на вход будут поданы данные, которые не отвечают изначально заданным правилам вложения.
Если нужно более гибко - пишите класс.
Наверное, так.